# Remove stat labels in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

All my labels show , Median [IQR] (or other statistics). I don't know how to remove them. I haven't added "add_stat_label" so according to all the guides they shouldn't be there. Does anyone know?

As example just the basic usage

```
trial2 %>% tbl_summary()
```

Can I remove the ,Median (IQR) etc

[Returned table with the basic code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMBBA.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please update your post with a _minimal_ reproducible example, aka a reprex https://reprex.tidyverse.org/